# Synchronized statement doesn't work the second time

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, synchronized

**UPDATE:**
Turns out there wasn't anything wrong with my Synchronized statements. I made a mistake earlier on in the code and it was blocking there. I apologize for the wasted time and thank you for all the help.

PS. The CountDownLatch suggested by @sh0rug0ru was better suited to my needs and was exactly what I needed.

**PREVIOUS:**

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
synchronized (readyLock) { //sets this thread's status to ready
readyLock.notify();
System.out.println("notify works");
try {
    readyLock.wait();
    System.out.println("woke up from sleep");
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Battleship_server_clientThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
readyLock.notify();
}
while (true) { //game loop             

//Some stuff here        

    synchronized (readyLock) { //sets this thread's status to ready
        readyLock.notify();
        System.out.println("notify works");
        try {
            readyLock.wait();
            System.out.println("woke up from sleep");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Battleship_server_clientThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        readyLock.notify();
    }
//Some more stuff here
}
```

The readyLock object is initialized in another class as a static final variable:

```
static final Object readyLock = new Object();
```

The Synchronized statement works the first time, as in the first synchronized block of statements. But the synchronized block inside the while loop doesn't work. It's the exact same code in both the places.

This class is a thread that is run twice from a server. It's for a two player game. The rest of the code is [here](https://github.com/fazerlicourice7/Battleships/blob/master/BattleshipServer/src/battleshipserver/Battleship_server_clientThread.java).

I'm trying to figure out why the second synchronized statement doesn't work. I think it's just blocking there for some reason.

**NOTE All the System.out.println(""); lines are for debugging.**

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What unexpected behavior do you actually see, or what expected behavior do you not see?

Comment: I don't know if this is related to your problem, but the first rule of Object.wait is that it must always be executed in a condition-based loop, as [described in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--).

Comment: @John Bollinger Like I said it seems like it's blocking or something. It doesn't do anything, when I expect it to print out the contents of the sout statements, and then move on to the rest of the code.

Comment: As @VGR says, `Object.wait()` should ordinarily be executed in a loop, because it is possible to have spurious wakeups.  Thus, after returning from `wait()` one tests whether the condition one was waiting on has in fact become true, and otherwise waits again.

Comment: Having two `notify()`s in each block is a bit suspicious, but we haven't enough code to tell whether it's wrong.

Comment: @Fazer, it sounds like you have a deadlock.  This could happen, for instance, if one thread performs all the `notify()`s it intends to perform *before* the other invokes `wait()`.  Do you in fact need to `wait()` at all?  What does one thread do while the other is waiting?

Comment: The waiting thread is waiting for the other thread to reach the same point in the code, so that it can access some variables that are being manipulated. I don't want to access these variables before they are manipulated (i.e. I don't want one thread to get too far in front of the other). This might happen because the clients may be interacting with the server at different speeds, so I want them to stay synchronized.

Comment: My logic behind the two notify()'s is that the 1st thread will first notify the other thread, telling it, that it's ready. It will then go to sleep. If the other thread is already waiting, then it will wake up and notify the 1st thread, which will also wake up. Else, if the other thread isn't waiting. The 1st one will just wait until the other one reaches this point and notifies the 1st one. After notifying, it will then wait, while the 1st one will notify it after waking up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `notify`, use `notifyAll`. `notify` will pick a random waiting thread. If that thread goes back to `wait` state and `notify` isn't called again, all the other waiting threads will stay waiting, and you have yourself a deadlock.

Using `notifyAll` will give all threads in `wait` state a chance to proceed.

`notify` is very dangerous, and there is almost no good reason to use it.

Better yet, why are you using `wait`/`notify`/`notifyAll` in the first place? What are you trying to achieve? Whatever concurrency pattern you are trying to implement probably already has an implementation in `java.util.concurrent` which will more clearly and more safely do whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: notifyAll(); didn't make a difference. I am currently looking at the API to see if anything fis my need. 
I'm looking for something that will make the current thread wait until the other thread is at the same point as it, then they continue.

Comment: Check out the [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). This allows threads to wait for another thread to reach a certain point.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `notify()`, this would come with a state change.

When you `wait()` you should check for that state change.

Otherwise you risk either;

- the `notify` is lost if nothing is waiting at that moment.
- `wait` can wake spuriously.

This is covered in the documentation for those methods.

Comment: It didn't work. I put the wait method into a loop that only exists after the desired state change. This state change occurs in the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments, the second `notify()` in each synchronized block is suspicious.  If the purpose for `wait()`ing is to make the two threads you describe take turns, so that only one runs at any given time, then your code is broken.  Here's what then actually happens:

1. One thread enters the (one of the) synchronized blocks, excluding all others.
2. That thread notifies one other blocked waiting on `readyLock`, if there is any, so that it can proceed when the current thread releases that monitor.
3. The current thread blocks, releasing the monitor and await a notification of its own.
4. The other thread does its thing, until it comes to the same or a similar block, at which time it notifies the waiting thread and thereafter itself begins waiting.
5. The original thread proceeds, immediately notifying the waiting thread.
6. The original thread exits the synchronized block, releasing the `readyLock`'s monitor
7. **The second thread can then return from `wait()`, running concurrently with the first.**

In itself, that does not explain a deadlock, but if you don't expect the two threads to be running concurrently then there's any number of ways trouble could ensue.

Here's how you might structure that scenario better:

```
synchronized (readyLock) {
    setMyTurn(false);
    otherPlayer.setMyTurn(true);
    readyLock.notify();
    while (!isMyTurn()) {
        try {
            readyLock.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Battleship_server_clientThread.class.getName()).log(
                Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you might want to consider `notifyAll()` instead of `notify()`.  The distinction doesn't matter if there can be only one other thread waiting on the monitor, but it is otherwise safer if all potential waiters utilize a loop and condition check as shown.

Comment: I already re-structured my code to something similar, after reading @Peter Lawrey 's answer. It didn't change the fact that it was blocking. But wouldn't I still need a notify(); after I return from wait? Because I only return from wait() when the other thread invokes notify(), and the other thread always wait() s after it notifies.

Comment: @Fazer, if the point is for the threads to alternate running, so that they never run concurrently after the first synchronization, then no you do not need and *do not want* to `notify()` immediately after returning from `wait()`,  You want to notify the other thread only when you're ready for it to run, which is not until the current thread is itself ready to wait again.  Of course, in that case you probably don't actually need two threads at all, as you could instead just have one alternate between the two workloads.

Comment: I don't neccessarily want them to alternate. I just need them to not run a certain part of the code, until both threads are at the same point. After both threads reach that point, they should be runnning simultaneously. The reason they might not synchronzie the rest of the code and always reach said point at the same time is because both threads interact with clients and the information they recieve from each client might not(probably won't) come at the same time.